# Same arguments type, is there any short method?

Tags: typescript

```
function setColor(r:number, g:number, b:number, a:number) { ... }
```

I don't want like this.

```
interface Color {
     r:number;
     g:number;
     b:number;
     a:number;
}
```

There is any way I can shorten iterative argument typing?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? You could make it less clear and more complicated, sure, but why?

Comment: So use `function setColor(col: Color) {…}` instead? It's not really clear what you want instead of the four parameters, and what hinders you from using the alternative that you want.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for correcting my grammar mistakes.

Comment: @Bergi 
If a function requires 10 factors, and all of them have numeric types, it is boring to write types over and over again.
For example, function Boo (a:number, b:number, c:number, d:number, e:number...).
I wonder if there is a more sophisticated and neat way. (with not using interface)

Comment: Just copy/paste `:number, ` part.

Comment: Is that the best way?
I asked because I thought there would be a more sophisticated way. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: you could certainly do this: https://tsplay.dev/mq1gdm

Comment: @keenshark Why would you not want to use an interface? Also a function taking 10 parameters does smell. Consider using an array (or at least a tuple) instead. If you really *want* to have 10 variables for 10 parameters, you have to declare their types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object properties are *not ordered*. Function arguments *are ordered*. That means there is *no way* to go from an an object type of many properties, to an ordered argument list of those properties.

So if you want the function signature that has 4 separate arguments, what you already have is your best bet.

---

If you want to reuse that order of parameters a lot, you can make a tuple type  to use for your functions:

```
type ColorParameters = [r: number, g: number, b: number, a: number]

function setColor(...[r, g, b, a]: ColorParameters) {
  //...
}

setColor(64, 192, 255, 0.1)
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJwAoENnoLYWBZAZygF4oBtZALigDsBXbAIwIBooBzGh5tqJ7oxbJ26Qb2QBdAFDSAZvVoBjYAEs4tKITzwkyABQA6Y5XYd2TUZJq6UGLLnxEAlFADe0qFAD0344ekAX1ltYFsDADYAFnYARgBOACZ2RIBWVPYABkNY5yA)

---

If you are willing to change your function to accept an object, you can do something like:

```
interface Color {
     r:number;
     g:number;
     b:number;
     a:number;
}

function setColor({ r, g, b, a }: Color) {
  //...
}

setColor({ r: 64, g: 192, b: 255, a: 0.1 })
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsA26rIN4BQyxxUAXCAK4C2ARtANxEnIDmFN9UTLytHdRsxJwBXJgF8CBGJRAIwwdCGQBnCGAzYoACjzIoAGjbHaxuMglk0WHAEp8zAPROAdO4JSC6zbd37yZAA2ABZjdmQARgBOACZTa1iAViTzawAGV0jLOyA)

Comment: The first code was the answer I wanted. Thank you very much.!!

Comment: @keenshark Glad I could help don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark if you believe it solved your problem.